# Deductions in Quickbooks Payroll

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, qbxml

We are trying to import some deduction information into Quickbooks from another system. I don't see anything that looks like deductions on this page http://developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html, and based on Internet searches, it looks like this is one of the features missing from the QB SDK. Is this still accurate?

Thanks,

Comment: What kind of deductions?

Comment: @WilliamLorfing Deductions in the payroll item (401(k), HSA, etc).